# Array range or synchronized reading from input file

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I´m trying to synchronize my process but I`ve got doubts about it. I've only one input file to read from.  I was thinking about synchronizing the read method to the threads.  Instead, what do you think about read the file into an array before creating the threads, and then dividing the array by the number of threads? Every thread only work with a range of this arrays.

Many thanks everyone.

Comment: Could'you post some code.

Comment: Hi! it's an idea before write code. The idea is a thread that process a single uid from a input file and insert it in database. When I create the thread I don't know if get a range of the array, after put the enter file in an array, for every thread or in the thread process synchornized the reading of the input file. What do you think? thanks!

Comment: You just want insert in database uid from a file. Is this file that big that you need multithreading ?

Comment: About 300.000 uids. It's to improve the performance. Is it the right way? Coworkers used it but i don't know if is the right way for only one input file, thanks!

Comment: Performance depends of lot of things. But launching 300 000 threads is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry! I don't explain me well. For example: with 2 threads configured, every thread insert 150.000 uids from a range array before read all the input file. Or pass the same file to every thread, and synchronized reading the file, then every thread read different uids from the file, and dont repeat the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance I can propose you some ways :

- If it's simple insert of the content of the file, you can use a LOAD DATA INFILE (mysql word) or bulk insert (oracle words), maybe you need to create another file from this one, in a single thread.
- You can split the file by 1000 or 10000 rows (example) and using multithreading to process files using a threadpool to manage the thread number https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html.
- Read the file in one thread and give the insert operation to another thread using threadpool (maybe the more simple).
- Using an ETL to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead, what do you think about read the file into an array before creating the threads, and then dividing the array by the number of threads? Every thread only work with a range of this arrays.

Yes, I think that this makes a lot more sense.  Typically when I am trying to process entries from a file, I have one thread that is reading from the file and then queuing up jobs for a thread-pool to do.  Then I can allocate a number of processing threads which are get the entries from the file and process them via an `ExecutorService`.  Dequeuing from a `BlockingQueue` is also possible depending on the implementation.

In semi code, this would look something like:

```
 // file reader
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_WORKERS);
 while (true) {
    line = file.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    threadPool.submit(new MyRunnable(line));
 }
 // shutdown the pool after we submit the last line
 threadPool.shutdown();
 ...

 // multiple thread processors
 public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String line;
    public MyRunnable(String line) {
       this.line = line;
    }
    public void run() {
        processLine(line);
    }
}
```

Instead of your threads fighting for access to the file, you isolate the reading to one thread and the processing to the others.